# Axis in scatterplot are not shown in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatterplot in matplotlib created as code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

#
#cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(rot=-.2, as_cmap=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="avg_PE_train",
                 y="sale_log",
                 hue="ARTCL_DESC",
                 legend = False,
                 s = 300,
                 data = ...)


# Set x-axis label
plt.xlabel('PE Values', fontsize = 35)
# Set y-axis label
plt.ylabel('Q4 2019 Sales (log scale)', fontsize = 35)
plt.axvline(x=-1, ls='--', color='r')
#sns.set(rc={'figure.facecolor':'white'})

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Arial'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['text.color'] = '#181a17'
plt.rcParams['axes.labelcolor']= '#181a17'
plt.rcParams['xtick.color'] = '#181a17'
plt.rcParams['ytick.color'] = '#181a17'
plt.rcParams['font.size']=30
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('black')
plt.xticks(size = 30)
plt.yticks(size = 30)
#plt.axis('on')
#ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
```

but it does not show the x axis or y axis (the labels are these axis are shown but I need to show the x and y axis or put a square around my entire graph

Comment: could you provide an example output ? it seems to be working fine for me (using seaborn tips dataset for sample data)

Comment: _A proper question **MUST** provide **ALL** of the information necessary in order for a proper answer to be given._ Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors, current output, expected output), as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Only images of plots are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the command:

```
plt.show()
```

at the end of your code.

Comment: I forgot to write that, I already have .show() at the end

Comment: I think because you might have commented out the last two lines of code you posted. Try not commenting them out.